# Tomcat Apache stopped suddenly

Tags: apache

My application is a GIS application:

- Servlet & JSP app
- Apache web server
- Oracle DB

My problem is that Apache stopped working after approximately 2 hours from restarting the service.

During these 2 hours the application ran successfully with no problems, and suddenly Apache stopped serving any more requests.

Comment: Since you've provided no error details, no diagnostics, just "I'm driving a model XYZ car and the motor won't start", we can't really help you.

Comment: I got what you need and really appreciate your reply , i will post after a while the snapshot of the log.

Comment: If you can help me in how to diagnose apache , it will be greet.